# python get link from website after post method

Tags: python, html, parsing, request

I have a small problem. There is a website: https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/ausschreibung/public where I would like to parse a link from. If you enter values in the 3 fields:

"Auschreibung ab" , "Produktart" , die nächsten"

you get a table from which I would like to get the download link (there is a blue picture with an arrow).

What I tried:

```
payload = {
        "suche.searchFrom":"03.12.2014",
        "suche.produktartSelection": "2",
        "suche.resultLimit":"10",
    }

headers = {
        'Referer': 'https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/ausschreibung/public',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0'
        }
with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/ausschreibung/public', data=payload,     verify=False, headers=headers)
    request= c.get('https://www.regelleistung.net/ip/action/ausschreibung/public') 

    html= str(request.content)
    result = re.search('<a class="button" href="/ip/action/ausschreibung/public?(.*)"><img    border="0" src="/ip/img/icon_download.png" ',html)
    result.group(1)
```

However it seems that the right link is not in the request.content. So I think that my "c.post" is wrong but I have no idea why and how to check.

You might wonder why I am not using beautifulsoup but I have some issues with proxies and try to work with the packages given in Anaconda.

Would be cool if anybody could give me a hint, what I am doing from in the post method.
Secondly, I would also appreciate if somebody knows a more sophisticated way to extract the link from the request.content..

THANK YOU!

Comment: You have tried [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ???

Comment: well as mentioned above I can't download the package due to proxy issues, so a solution without would be appreciated